# Make rebuilds everytime

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have a Makefile as :

```
    BUILD_DIR= $(BASE_DIR)/build
    _OBJ := a.o  b.o  
    CLEAN_OBJECTS := $(_OBJ)
    .PHONY: clean

    create_code:          
            python ../script/my_script.py

    all: create_code $(_OBJ)
    $(_OBJ): %.o: %.c        
            mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
            $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATH) -c $< -o $@
            cp *.o $(BUILD_DIR)

clean:
        rm -f $(CLEAN_OBJECTS)
```

The target create_code executes the python script and generates a set of .c/.h files.
The target _obj compiles them.
Every time I run `make all` , `create_code` target is run even though there is no change to .c/.h generated earlier .

Any suggestions on why this is happening and  how to make this create_code target run only if `make clean` was done earlier .

Comment: What file(s) does `python ../script/my_script.py` actually generate -- if any?

Comment: it generates the .c/.h files which are used by $(_obj) target to compile.

Comment: It looks like you have circular dependencies here. create_code target depends on objects and generates source code, and _OBJ target depends on source code and generates objects.

Comment: And do those .c/.h file have any dependencies?  That is, what are the .c/.h files generated *from*?

Comment: @n.m I added create_code: $(_OBJ) as an experiment . Otherwise it is a empty pre-requisite.. I am removing it as it causes confusion.

Comment: @G.M the script generates some functions using python libraries and places it in .c/.h files . I run make clean & make all , all the .c/.h/.o are created. when I run make all again , it should not run create_code target again .

Comment: If your script *reads* files A B and C, and *generates* files X Y and Z, then your rule should be `X Y Z: A B C`. Your `create_code` is a made up name, not corresponding to any real file; such rules run every time.

Comment: the script actually looks at a db and generates X Y Z files containing data and functions to manage it. Everything is done programatically and there are no A B C files. what  prerequisite can i give to create_code that can tell it to run only if  X Y Z are out of date.

Comment: This is an interesting situation. Normally make looks at the filesystem-provided time stamps of the dependencies, but it cannot look inside a database, even if records there have an internal timestamp. So your tools that update the database should create or touch a dummy file which would provide the timestamp for your rule.

Comment: If I merge my create_code rule's reciepe into the _obj rule,  wont it mean that run  _obj's recipe only when .c /.h files have changed, given that If  i am expecting a change  in .c/.h file , i should be doing make clean and make all .

Comment: As an alternative you could generate a `makefile` `gen-src.mk` based on the state of the database and then include that in your top level `makefile`.  `gen-src.mk` would contain any rules required to rebuild the sources from the database contents.

Comment: Reiterating the problem statement, i do make clean & make all , I go to db and generated  all files (.c/.h)i need ,went ahead and compiled them . Next time , i donot want to go to db again , as i am sure there is no change to Db, db hardly changes but can change.I go and check if .c/.h/.o files are present and not out date , do not execute any of the targets. I save 3mins time with every make all. - i did not see your recent post.

Comment: @GM , yes i could do that or rather i should do that . I was trying to find any thing simpler. What is your opinion about merging the rules part I mentioned. i tried dint work , couldnot figured why it dint work.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is that you have one or more generated files that depend on something other than the underlying file system -- namely the contents of your database.

One possibility would be to take advantage of the fact that `make`, having invoked a rule to rebuild a target will, nonetheless, always check the update time of that target when it is specified as a prerequisite in any other rule.

So, given the rule (untested)...

```
.PHONY: FORCE
%.c: FORCE
        command-to-generate-source $@.tmp
        diff -q $@.tmp $@ || cp $@.tmp $@
```

Invoking `make foo.c` from the command line.  `make` will run the commands...

```
command-to-generate-source foo.c.tmp
diff -q foo.c.tmp foo.c || cp foo.c.tmp foo.c
```

where `command-to-generate-source foo.c.tmp` is expected to leave its output in `foo.c.tmp`.  If the newly generated output file is different than the existing file the `cp` operation will be run and, hence, the target timestamp will be updated and anything dependent on the target will be updated accordingly.

If, however, the newly generated output file is the same as the existing one then no `cp` will be run, the target file will be left untouched and `make` will not consider it to be changed when it appears as a prerequisite in other rules.

This is just one possibility but it's the obvious one given that you already have most (if not all) of the required logic in the command `python ../script/my_script.py`.

Comment: Thanks for your input ... but my problem is more so that i donot want to generate the file everytime, File generation part is little time consuming and i want to avoid that. Nonetheless , you gave me some clue to do this .I will try it out and comment here.